# Raspberry pi with DP 4.1 cannot get IP from switch

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi3, android-things

As far as I figured out, Raspberry pi 3 which runs DP 4.1 cannot get IP address from my switch. Other devices on switch like PC's running windows or Rasbian installed Rasberries can get IP address as it should and be able to communicate each other. I tested my pi with both WiFi and cable connected router and it was able to get IP address normally. So I'm nearly sure that there is no problem on my Ethernet cable, pi or switch.

As a last note, the switches is Cisco sg100d-05 and I cannot use a router instead of this switch.

Is there anything that I can do to join this closed network on switch?

Comment: It is a general system / network question and off-topic for StackOverflow (not programming related). I would suggest to post that in SuperUser or on a more appropriate board.

Comment: But as I stated, all the other devices that i connected to the switch can get an ip properly. I thought that it is an android iot problem. Do you still suggest to post the question to other platforms?

Comment: I don't see where you have any code-concern here. As you describe it, it's a  Android system network problem, not a problem from an Android program you are writing, or maybe I haven't understood your question well enough.

Comment: I've noticed that my RPI3 running DP 4.1 and 5.1 can connect to my office ethernet, but not my home ethernet. Not sure why. If practical you might try another network to isolate the problem.

Comment: I solved my problem, first, i assigned ip, netmask and broadcast addresses maually with ifconfig. After that i was able to see the recieved data from the device that i try ping the pi, but pi is responding from wlan0, not eth0. So routing or disabling the wifi solves the problem.